# Não consigo pegar nome de arquivo e salvar em banco de dados

Tags: javascript, html

serei mais especifico, tenho o sistema que funciona da seguinte forma, ele faz uma varredura numa pasta e pega todos os arquivos txt da pasta e me mostra em forma de link, ao clicar no link ele me mostra o que tem dentro dos arquivos txt. ótimo, funciona blz, porém, agora no codigo html tenho um formulario que deve cadastrar no banco de dados o nome do arquivo txt e uma observação sobre o mesmo, aí que ta pegando, não consigo pegar o nome do arquivo e gravar no banco o seu nome e uma observacao sobre o mesmo.

[Download do arquivo para entendimento](http://www.midiacloud.com/estudo/estudoChat.zip)

Comment: `arr[i].nomeArquivo` já não tem o nome do arquivo ? O que não está exatamente conseguindo fazer? Não vejo aqui nada referente a banco de dados

Comment: Agora preciso pegar essa informação (nome do arquivo) e junto com ela um textarea para comentar sobre o arquivo e jogar para o banco de dados

Comment: E onde está o código para fazer isso ?  Vejo tags de javascript e html, mas isso seria php. Já tem o código que faz a ligação ao banco de dados ? Se sim edite a pergunta e acrescente esse código

Comment: Consegue colocar mais informações no código?

Comment: vou editar o codigo para entenderem